# CONTAR SIN REPETIR Y MOSTRAR SOLO ULTIMO CARGADO

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqldb

Hola todos tengo esta consulta: Necesito contar cuantos OK Y NG tengo en total, el problema es que a medida que voy cargando se van repitiendo los numeros de serie y necesito que cuente solamente el ultimo del dato duplicado. es decir en este caso tengo dos duplicados que son el T-04 y AP2, de esos dos duplicados debería contar solo el ultimo que se cargo del T-04 Y AP2 CON MAYOR FECHA Y HORARIO.

```
SELECT
`N° Sector`,
`N° Serie`,
(`Fecha de Chequeo`),
`Estado Gral.`,
COUNT(`Estado Gral.`) AS Total
FROM extintores
GROUP BY `N° Serie`,`Estado Gral.`
ORDER BY `N° Sector` DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende. Pulsa en [edit] y explica con claridad el asunto. Pon un ejemplo de los resultados esperados, eso ayudará a entender lo que quieres. Gracias.

Comment: Ayúdanos con un ejemplo de cómo sería el resultado final a modo de retroalimentación de tu pregunta principal.

Comment: hoy la consulta me esta contando 39  registros pero tengo 2 duplicados , entonces el resultado real debería ser 37 ya que tengo que omitir los duplicados y contar solo el ultimo que se cargo

Comment: @RodrigoCastillo una manera de probar para solventar es que en tu consulta obtengas la fecha máxima, eso nos devolvería para los duplicados el último registro de esos 2, algo así: **`MAX(`Fecha de Chequeo`)`**

Comment: probe hacerlo pero no me dio resultado me sigue mostrando los dos registros  y me cuenta los dos

Comment: @RodrigoCastillo es decir ¿de los repetidos, solo debe mostrar el mas reciente pero en el conteo mostrar por ejemplo 2 en cada caso de los repetidos no?

Comment: De los repetidos solo debe mostrar el mas reciente , para asi cuando cuente siempre me cuente el mas reciente.

Comment: Por eso, para los repetidos entonces en el Total debe mostrar 2 o 1?, es que en función de comprender eso puedo o no dar una posible solución

Comment: solo 1 el ultimo cargado

Comment: si tengo 2 o mas duplicados de un numero de serie que me muestre 1 solo y que sea el ultimo cargado para que cuente correctamente y no me cuente todos los duplicados cargados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso en especifico yo lo resolvería incluyendo una subconsulta donde me arroje la ultima fecha que yo tenga en mis registros, y hacer un join con ella para tener solo el ultimo registro.

```
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT EX2.`N° Serie`, MAX(EX2.`Fecha de Chequeo`) `Fecha de Chequeo`
      FROM extintores EX2
      GROUP BY EX2.`N° Serie`
  )Tmp
```

Esta subconsulta únicamente me arrojara el ultimo registro de cada serie que tenga en mi tabla, en base a la fecha, y es a la que yo hare join en mi consulta principal.

Y este seria la consulta final.

```sql
SELECT
  ext.`N° Sector`,
  ext.`N° Serie`,
  ext.`Fecha de Chequeo`,
  ext.`Estado Gral.`,
  COUNT(ext.`Estado Gral.`) AS Total
FROM extintores ext
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT EX2.`N° Serie`, MAX(EX2.`Fecha de Chequeo`) `Fecha de Chequeo`
      FROM extintores EX2
      GROUP BY EX2.`N° Serie`
  )Tmp ON ext.`N° Serie`=Tmp.`N° Serie` and ext.`Fecha de Chequeo` =Tmp.`Fecha de Chequeo`
GROUP BY `N° Serie`,`Estado Gral.`
ORDER BY `N° Sector` DESC
```

Comment: Excelente Funciono Perfectamente! Mucha Gracias!!